# On the Samsung Galaxy S5, how do I change the default USB connection type?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-5

Right now when I plug my S5 into a computer, the USB connection defaults to 'installer'. I then have to pull down the notifications menu and switch it to 'MTP'.

I'd like it to default to MTP, so I don't have to fool with the phone after plugging it in.

Phone is from Verizon, and Android version is 4.4.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable the developer options, which allow setting a default USB mode.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code on the dialer, it will then go to a page called USBSettings, there, you can change the connection type 
*#0808#
try dialling this again if the first time it just erases text 
:-)